# How to unit test RxJava Completable.error on Android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a function that returns a Completable which returns `Completable.error(RuntimeException("message"))` if another function fails or `Completable.complete()` if not.

I was trying to write a unit test for this and see that the flow is going correctly to the error and success code but in my test I cannot differentiate between them using

`underTest.unregisterFromService().test().assertComplete().assertNoErrors()`

Does anyone know how the `Completable.error()` value can be checked in unit test?

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
yourCompletable
    .test()
    .assertErrorMessage("your error message")
```

Comment: This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There is an `assertError` for that, most cases use the version that takes the `Thorwable`'s type as a parameter, from the docs:

> Asserts that this TestObserver/TestSubscriber received exactly one onError event which is an instance of the specified errorClass class.

Usage:

```
yourCompletable
    .test()
    .assertError(RuntimeException::class.java)
```

[Here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#assertError-java.lang.Class-) you can find the three versions of `assertError`.

Comment: I get an `java.lang.AssertionError: No errors (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 1)` with that which is why was confused :(

Comment: Well, maybe the case you're testing doesn't terminate with a RuntimeException?, a code like this Completable.error(RuntimeException("message"))
      .test()
      .assertError(RuntimeException::class.java), passes the test!
If you need help with the function's code, share it so we can help.

Comment: Is there a way to test the exception message?

Comment: You can do that with the predicate version of assertError
`public final U assertError(Predicate<Throwable> errorPredicate)`
so it goes like this in Kotlin for example, `assertError { it.message == expectedMessage }`

Comment: To test the error message there is a better API:
public final U assertErrorMessage(String message)